# How to turn off the foreign constraint by using the hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I am importing and exporting between two databases,  and the problem when I want to add some tabels to the new it raises the error regarding the constrains. 
I know how to turn this directly by using the mySQL:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

however, I want to use something like sission or query to send this command to the database. 
I have tried something like this:

```
Query q = session2.createQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0");
```

and this also didn't work.

Comment: Use `createNativeQuery`. (I think it is the **JPA** method, see around for `createSqlQuery` or similar...)

Comment: Instead of disabling the constraint checks I'd analyze why they are being violated and fix that. After all those constraints are probably there for a reason.

Comment: also 'createSqlQuery' is not working as well.

Comment: @Thomas I know the problem in the database its only complaining about the constraint when I add table before the other, it's not dangerouse however, I have like 65 tables and I want to do this automaticly.

Comment: When you add a table you shouldn't have any problems as constraint checks are executed when adding/changing rows in those tables. Anyways you still should use the correct order even when doing it automatically (you need to define the order in that case). As an alternative you could try and add the constraints only after the tables have been created and filled though I'd not prefer that.

Comment: Is it a setting you always want to be active?

Comment: @Bohemian yes I want to turn it on and after the session is ending I want to turn it off.

Comment: @HajrasElGdiryHG did you get the ans ?

Comment: I think this is not possible in Hibernate, instead I had to change my schema.